# What are the most important keys(keyboard keys) should be disabled in a web site?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering about how to secure our web sites from external parties. Because as we know, all the source codes are visualized for the others via view source code(form CTRL + u, right click -> view page source, F12) option that is provided by every browsers. So that up to some extent  , we can secure our web pages by restricting those options via disabling keys.

I feel happy that, I have already disabled CTRL, right click and F12 button. Now my source code is bit secured from viewing.

My question is, what are the other important keys(except above mentioned) should be disabled for secure the source code by not showing it to external parties?

Comment: I can disable Javascript and your "security" is all gone. Instead, don't send sensitive information to the client side.

Comment: Whether a person sees your markup or not has absolutely nothing to do with whether or not your site is secure. And, also, you can't prevent people from seeing your markup (that is simply how the web works).

Comment: The JS and HTML on your sites are run clientside, so the only way to "secure" that code is to block all users from reaching those sites.

Comment: In addition disabling the keyboard and mouse is a) rude b) frustrating for users and c) makes your site inaccessible to a large swath of users. Bad idea all around.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have another question. Lets say if we publish a document for external users which is only for read not to download or save. How can I do it?

Comment: 1. Please create a new question if you have one. This ensures that the question and answer is usable for others.

Comment: 2. You simply cannot have read only documents on the web. You might create something like that with a ebook format with DRM, where you revoke the key after reading. But that does not keep people from using screenshots to copy the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is not the answer you are looking for:
Everyting that you have to transmit to the client to render **is** on the client. So even if you break the usual functionality of a web browser by denying certain actions, that will not make your application more secure.

**There is no such thing as security by obscurity.**

Disabling JS will render all your measures void. Even tools like Firebug or Chrome's dev console will grant the user access to all he wants to know.

If you need to secure your stuff, only display the results and do the processing on the server.

So to come back to your question:

> Q: What are the most important keys(keyboard keys) should be disabledin a web site?
>
> A: None!